# How to connect to an Oracle RAC from Symfony2 using TNSNAMES.ora?

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, oracle11g

I'm currently developing a web app (Using symfony 2.4) that's gonna connect to an Oracle Real Application Cluster. I'm writing code against an Oracle XE to get the most similar enviroment posible, but as I'm looking for information I haven't found much on this.

I'm looking for some info but I haven't found much (I found [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5106)) but I seem to be lacking some information. 
Where should I put the tnsnames.ora file? Which content should I put in the database configuration parameters?